# sum of products for that using k-map

Tags: logic

I have a logic question:

If I have: f(A,B,C,D) = M(4,7,8,11).D(1,2,13,14)

what would be the sum of products for that using k-map (please note that this is big-m and you have to find the answer in the sum of products)

I drew the k-map, the problem is, I can't find a way to cover the zeros without having to state 4 terms each with 4 boolean terms (A,B,C,and D) without using the D terms, is that right?

Note: this is a homework question, i don't want the answer as much as i want to be able to solve this myself.

```
   +---+---+---+---+
00 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
   +---+---+---+---+
01 | x | 1 | x | 1 |
   +---+---+---+---+
11 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
   +---+---+---+---+
10 | x | 1 | x | 1 |
   +---+---+---+---+
     00  01  11  10
```

I edited the map because it was made for little m and this is big m

Comment: I am just guessing that M lists when it should be 1 and Ds are dont-cares? Please do elaborate!

Comment: yeah it is Karnaugh Map and M is big-M while Ds are don't cares (big-M is where the result is represented in product of sums)

Comment: How about showing us your Karnaugh map?  You show us yours and we'll... well, you know.  Make up an answer.

Comment: The Karnaugh map looks like a quarter of a chessboard. With labels 00, 01, 11, 10 along the x and y axis, it looks like this: 0101\nx0x0\n0101\nx0x0  Here the origin is in the top left corner, x runs from left to right, and y runs from top to bottom.

Comment: I added a picture.  I hope it's right.

Comment: Yes, this is what I have. It is not possible to simplify the circuit. You obviously do not want to turn any x into a 1. The crux of the difficulty - you CANNOT for any 1 flip just one bit in its address and  get to another 1. By "address" I mean the 4 bits. Here addresses range from 0x0 to 0xF, or 0000 to 1111. Think about why they write 00 01 11 10 and not 00 01 10 11 - because they want to be able to reach a neighbor in the S/W/N/E direction by flipping exactly 1 bit. Notice that they can go from 10 to 00 in one bit flip as well. Your lonely chessboard presents no opportunity for simplifictn

Comment: so the only purpose of this question is to say that there is no way of simplifying this circuit?

Comment: Replace "to say" with illustrate. Yes, it is good to illustrate that there are some formulas(, not circuits - you were not given a circuit. Circuits do not have don't care conditions, only formulas do) that are already as simple as they can be. Well, not quite. I hope you appreciate the ordering 00 01 11 10

Comment: Wait a second! In this case this thing is simplifiable! You can see it, right?

Comment: how? there are no zeros beside each other, it is just like the case of ones but with zeros isn't it? (with big-m you account for zeros not ones)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this:

```
\ AB 00 01  11  10
CD +---+---+---+---+
00 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
   +---+---+---+---+
01 | x | 0 | x | 0 |
   +---+---+---+---+
11 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
   +---+---+---+---+
10 | x | 0 | x | 0 |
   +---+---+---+---+

Simplest answer = OR(AND(*,*,*,*), AND(*,*,*,*), AND(*,*,*,*), AND(*,*,*,*)) where
You can use A, B, C, D, NOT(A), NOT(B), NOT(C), NOT(D) instead of *
===================================================================
```

Haha, this questions is constructed like that on purpose!

They asked you for worst case imaginable.

The don't-cares do not help AT ALL and the ones aren't next to each other.

When you have the (at most 4x4 because you can visualize that) K-map drawn out, do not bother to cover zeroes instead of ones hoping that it will be simpler.

When in k-map, it should be all there in front of you.

This was a trick question. For extra points you can reason why the circuit is not simplifiable, perhaps look it up in the literature. Also, there is a great deal of symmetry here, so perhaps you can get creative when you draw out the corresponding circuit. If you do it right, the picture should look very nice.

***EDIT:***

You can install this software for Linux and play with it:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gkmap/

It should convince you that your function is not simplifiable.

Comment: I edited the map because it was made for little m and this is big m

Comment: I do not understand the difference between M and m, I had to guess. Please do not assume that we used the same notation 5-50 years ago when learning this subject.

Comment: Actually, I take it back - the formula is NOT(OR(AB, nAnB, CnD, nCD)), which is pretty simple, but is not the standard form. Here nA = NOT(A). When you switch between m and M, you either keep the first NOT or not. I am not sure what sort of answer your teacher expects. Do play with the software please.